# Meteor reactive-var package is missing the equals() method, is this a bug?

Tags: meteor, equals

I'm learning about reactive programming in Meteor:

https://stephenwalther.com/archive/2014/12/05/dont-do-react-understanding-meteor-reactive-programming

I believe that the idea behind [Session.equals(key, value)](https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html#Session-equals) is to remember an association between the reactive variable and the desired value so that updates only propagate to the surrounding code if the equality changes. That way if we have hundreds of views that depend on the variable, only the old and new views get their update code triggered when the value changes.

Note that this would not be the case if we called `Session.get(key) === value` because every view's code would be called when the variable changes. This is discussed further under the **Session.get versus Session.equals()** section of the article.

But I found an inconsistency under the **Using Reactive Variables** section where it says:

```
Notice that a reactive variable, unlike the Session object, does not have an equals() method. Yes, that is a shame.
```

So [reactive-var](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-var.html) is missing `equals()` but [reactive-dict](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-dict.html) has [ReactiveDict.equals()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/reactive-dict.html#ReactiveDict-equals).

I can't really see a conceptual reason to exclude `ReactiveVar.equals()`. Maybe they had no context for storing the association, or maybe there is some scoping or other issue with Javascript that prevents this that I don't fully understand.

So my question is: **is this a bug?**

Should I just always use `reactive-dict`? In which case I would change everything from:

```
let myReactiveVar = new ReactiveVar();
...
if(myReactiveVar.get() === 'myValue')
```

To the more verbose (but performant):

```
let myReactiveDict = new ReactiveDict();
...
if(myReactiveDict.equals('myReactiveVar', 'myValue'))
```

Which would match the functionality provided by [Session.equals()](https://docs.meteor.com/api/session.html#Session-equals).

Another option would be to extend the `ReactiveVar` prototype with my own `equals()` method or inherit it in a child class and provide a `MyReactiveVar.equals()` method. Kudos if someone can provide examples to do either of these workarounds that we could submit as a pull request to the Meteor maintainers.

**Update**: I forgot to mention that ReactiveVar does take an `equalsFunc` optional parameter in its constructor. It might be possible to hack that as a reactive code block to partially implement `equals()` functionality without extending the class. Also, here is a [related issue on GitHub](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/issues/4073).

**Update**: to save time, here is the relevant source code for [ReactiveVar](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/reactive-var/reactive-var.js) and [ReactiveDict.equals()](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/master/packages/reactive-dict/reactive-dict.js#L158-L217). I believe that the `value` parameter gets converted to `serializedValue` and is then added as a dependency in `ReactiveDict`, but I still don't see why it wouldn't be possible to do something similar for `ReactiveVar`.

Answer (score 1):

The reason there's no `equals` method for `ReactiveVar` is because `set` only invalidates the computations is the new value differs from the current value.

> Sets the current value of the ReactiveVar, invalidating the Computations that called get if newValue is different from the old value.

```
const example = new ReactiveVar(0);

Tracker.autorun(() => {
  console.log(example.get());
});

example.set(1); // logs 1
example.set(0); // logs 0
example.set(0); // doesn't log
```

This is similar behaviour to `ReactiveDict`'s `equals` method.

Note that `set` on `ReactiveDict` does not behave this way. Calling `set` broadcasts that the value has changed. If you want to prevent the computation from invalidating, that is when you would use `equals`.

> Set a value for a key in the ReactiveDict. Notify any listeners that the value has changed (eg: redraw templates, and rerun any Tracker.autorun computations, that called ReactiveDict.get on this key.)

Comment: While that's true, it still doesn't answer my original performance question about hundreds of views that listen on something like `Session.equals(key, value)` so that only the old and new views get their update called when the Session's value no longer matches the desired value. That can be accomplished with `ReactiveDict.equals(key, value)` but not with `ReactiveVar`, and I don't see a reason for that yet. Many thanks for your quick response though.

Comment: It's the same. `set` only invalidates if the value changes. Any comparisons would change if the reactive var changed. When the reactive var changes, all computations *have* to re-run. None of them can be equal anymore. It's the same as `.equals`, it just invalidates the computation at a different stage.

Comment: I'm not sure that's true. If we have `if(Session.equals('myVar', 0))`, `if(Session.equals('myVar', 1))` and `if(Session.equals('myVar', 2))`, and we call `Session.set('myVar', 0)` then `Session.set('myVar', 1)`, then only the code for the 0 and 1 cases will be run. The code for case 2 will never be run, because myVar is never equal to 2. Whereas if we use `if(Session.get('myVar') === 0)` and so on for the other numbers, then all code for any `Session.get('myVar')` would be called see?

Comment: @ZackMorris You're right. Tested it here: https://gist.github.com/joshleblanc/9d9509e0d6e33d24fa3e0653112ad772

Comment: Hey thanks for taking the time to test that. If I read it right, all `Tracker` are called initially. Then  `console.log("var changed", v.get());` is called anytime that `v`changes. Whereas `console.log("Running a === 1"); d.equals('a', 1)` is only called when `d` transitions from `0 to 1` and `1 to 2`. It's not called for `2 to 3` and up. The `Tracker`  `d.equals('a', 2)` works similarly but for `2`.